# Byte array to int C#

Tags: c#, arrays, bitconverter

I am triyng to convert byte array into an int value
however I am getting an exception:

> "Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the
>   collection. Check array index and length."

the exception is on line:

```
int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes_length, 0);
```

byte _length contain the value (0x00,0x09);

here is my code:

```
byte[] bytes_length = new byte[Value_of_length];                   
//copy the byte byte array to the correct length.
Array.Copy(data, Place_of_length, bytes_length, 0,bytes_length.Length
int length = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes_length, 0);
```

Comment: This code sample does not appear to be complete.  Critically, we can't see where Value_of_length comes from.

Comment: As you can tell, ToInt32() requires an array with at least 4 bytes.  You have only 2, you could at best call ToInt16().

Comment: Int32 is so called because has 32 bits (4 bytes long)

Comment: int length = (int)BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes_length, 0);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Int32` needs 32 bits, or four bytes. Your array contains only two bytes, which means that you cannot convert it to `Int32`.

You can either convert it to `Int16`

```
int length = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes_length, 0);
```

or to extend two more bytes to the array before `Int32` conversion.

Moreover, you can skip copying altogether:

```
int length = BitConverter.ToInt16(data, Place_of_length);
```

Comment: And, of course, once this is corrected, there's no need for the array copying steps that come before either. It should just be `int length = BitConverter.ToInt16(data,Place_of_length);`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, that's right! Thank you!